# Help with integrating Snipcart

Tags: install

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://snipcart.com/blog/integrating-snipcart-with-craft-cms-a-child-s-play), but I'm stuck. I create the `layout.html` file and the `index.html` and it's still not working. Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What happens before you started working with snipcart?
For example, what happens when you visit `localhost:8080/Elementhal.dev/`

Answer (score 1):

I'll be the first to admit, I know nothing about snipcart so my answer could be way off.

Since your site works without snipcart, that means you are here:

> Once the installation is completed, simply login into the Craft admin and go to Settings. You will have to create the fields that will be required to define a Snipcart product. In the settings, click on Fields and create 2 new fields:

Once you have those fields created, you will need to create a new section - which is a **Channel**

> Name: Store
>
> Handle: store
>
> Section Type: Channel
>
> Uncheck Entries in this section have their own URLs

Once you have that done, and the entry fields created/updated as they suggest, I think where you went wrong is with the actual `layout.html` file.

> You need to include Snipcart’s JavaScript file and jQuery if it is not already included. Use the default CSS theme that you need to include as well.

What that is telling me is to open `layout.html` that I downloaded with snipcart and copy/paste all of the appropriate javascript into this file:

```
/path-to-your-project/craft/templates/_layout.html
```

That's the default layout template that Craft uses. So by pasting all of the necessary javascript & css into that file, each entry will have access to it.

Hope this helps!